# How to remove the first few characters of a string?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have here this string `'+ + + + + R1 VSS VDD GND 3123123'` and need to remove all first `'+'` characters from it. I wrote this code here,

```
def clear_string(s):
    c = "+"
    for j in range(0, len(c)):
        s = s.replace(c[j], "")
    return s
```

but it removes all the `'+'` characters from the string, but I need to delete only the first `'+'` symbols, how to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`lstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove any leading characters in your string that match a given set of characters. In this case, you want to remove `'+'` and spaces.

**Demo**

```
>>> s = "+ + + + + R1 VSS VDD GND 312312"
>>> s.lstrip("+ ")
'R1 VSS VDD GND 312312'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '+ + + + + R1 VSS VDD GND 3123123'

s.lstrip(' +')
Out[13]: 'R1 VSS VDD GND 3123123'
```

If you need to keep the leading spaces intact:

```
s.replace('+','',5) #limit the times you do the replace operation, only works if you know how many to do
Out[14]: '     R1 VSS VDD GND 3123123'
```

Comment: It's unclear from the question that OP actually wants to lose the spaces too, but seems a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, a simple regex will work too (although the already proposed `lstrip` is better for simple replacements):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'^(\+\s*)+', '', '+ + + + + R1 VSS VDD GND 3123123')
'R1 VSS VDD GND 3123123'
>>> re.sub(r'^(\+\s*)+', '', '+ + + + + R1 VSS VDD GND 3123123 ++++')
'R1 VSS VDD GND 3123123 ++++'
```

Answer (score -1):

You could run a loop starting from the beginning and count upto the index where the + signs end in this case  when you get str[i]=='R' so now that you have your index from where your string starts just get that part using a slice like str[5:]